# Type cast certain values in a nested list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nested

I have a nested list of strings:

`station_data = [['65.29', 3003', 'station1'], ['81.23', '8000', 'station2'], ['77.33', '3500', 'station3']]` etc...

I am trying to type cast the first position [0] of each list from string to float

I am trying to type cast the second position [1] of each sub list from string to int

I have tried different for loops, but for the life of me I cannot seem to get the syntax right

station_data can be modified, or a new list can be created, fine either way.

Desired output should look like:
`station_data_processed = [[65.29, 3003, 'station1'], [81.23, 8000, 'station2'], [77.33, 3500, 'station3']]`

Any suggestions are a huge help, thank you!

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: In short, we're happy to fix code with a single problem.  We are not a coding service.  Post your code as specified, and let us correct *your* error.

Comment: `[[float(x), int(y), z] for [x, y, z] in station_data]` although this does not handle cases where data is not able to be coerced. you'll need to figure that one out on your own based on desired output

Comment: `station_data = [[float(elem[0]), int(elem[1]), elem[2]] for elem in station_data]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a list comprehension:

```
converted_list = [[float(i[0]), int(i[1]), i[2]] for i in station_data]
```

Comment: Excellent, this works wonderfully. I have almost no experience with list comprehensions, but this gives me a good example to start incorporating them more.

Comment: Keep in mind this kind of assumes the input data will never be bad. You might want to implement some form of error handling if the final type of each element is really important.

Comment: This is a bad answer. Hardcoded and will not help others in the long turn. I have no idea why people have voted this post answer 3 times.

Comment: Because it answers the question exactly: how to type cast a nested list of strings. It can be easily extrapolated to other use cases.

Comment: imagine a user has a hundred thousand elements in a nested list. They won't live long enough to write `float(I[0])` for every other element.

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of `try/except`'s

```
station_data = [['65.29', '3003', 'station1'], ['81.23', '8000', 'station2'], ['77.33', '3500', 'station3']]
l = []
for lst in station_data:
    group = []
    for val in lst:
        try:
            val = int(val)
        except ValueError:
            try:
                val = float(val)
            except ValueError:
                pass
        group.append(val)
    l.append(group)
```

output

```
[[65.29, 3003, 'station1'], [81.23, 8000, 'station2'], [77.33, 3500, 'station3']]
```

Comment: I'm not sure about this one. In case of bad input your approach hides the error instead of letting the user know something is wrong.

Comment: Better than a hardcoded answer. It is best to provide a longer lasting option. The answer you provided works for the OP's case and only the OP's case. Generally when posting answers on SO, you want to avoid only hardcoded answers as they will not help future users accomplish there task.

Comment: An how exactly is casting elements to an unknown type a long lasting solution?

Comment: let me tell you, it's better than a hardcoding an answer buddy.